# Возможность закрывать вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Допустим у пользователя `X` есть привилегия закрывать вопросы с меткой `A`, может ли он  отредактировать любой вопрос, добавив туда эту метку, и тут же его закрыть?

Ответа на мете не нашел, Проверять сам не стал...

Comment: После 2к репутации любой участник и так может править любой вопрос. Может добавить метку. И может потом закрыть как дубль, если есть голд бадж по метке.

Comment: Насколько я помню, Grundy частенько в чате просил кого-то другого навесить метку javascript, чтобы закрыть вопрос своим голдхаммером. Так что насколько я понимаю -- не может.

Comment: @AK интересно 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, не просто закрывать, а только как дубликаты. Во-вторых, нет, не может: если он сам добавит метку, то его голос будет всего лишь одним из 5. Вроде бы можно чтобы метку добавил кто-то другой, но я не уверен - изначально вообще говорилось только о метках, которые стояли изначально.

Comment: не, если сам повесил - даже не даст проголосовать вроде

Comment: @Grundy, я ж так и сказал.

Comment: Не, ты сказал, что бахнуть нельзя будет, а голос посчитается, а мне кажется голосовать нельзя было, но уже не уверен

Comment: @Grundy, голосовать же даже за вопросы без метки можно.

Comment: @Grundy, *не, если сам повесил - даже не даст проголосовать вроде* — мне «давало» (да, «один из пяти»).